# Solidity error when encoding arguments to query public mapping

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, mapping, query

While developing a Smart Contract with Solidity on [Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org) , after creating the contract I'm trying to query a public mapping:

```
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
```

but when I call `balanceOf` for address `0x9b9731b07b9b5f982289bab87097eade6a4bc25d` it throws the following error:

> Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 2

Any idea how can I properly call `balanceOf`?

Comment: It works ok when input is an integer such as 0, 1, 2, ... and response is ok too, giving the right balance. Problem is input cannot be an address and this is what it should be.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The address needs be surrounded with quotes.
"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c" should work.

Answer (score 2):

The address has to be provided with quotes. Just like huafu said. Must be double qutoes "". It is not going to work with single qutoes. In Javascript it doesn't matter and I was trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.

**This works:**
"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c"

**This doesn't work.** 
'0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c'

Answer (score 1):

```
contract MyToken
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    ...
}
```

Reference - [The DAO](https://etherscan.io/address/0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413#code), version 1.0 with the $50 million bug.

Comment: Thx, using a query function, but what is the point of defining the mapping as public? I thought, beeing public meant anyone could ask for its values directly, right?

Comment: After creating balanceOf function, same error appears: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token...

Comment: Have you put quotes around the address?

Comment: Thanks! Now it works: "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c"